# Why does Rails console create so many Ruby processes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, process, cron, rake

I experimented with a Rake task with Cron. I started with no Ruby processes, then the Cron job started and spawned one process. The highlighted process below is what is run by Cron, which is expected:

[image]

I wanted to check if any records were being written to the database.  I ran `rails c` to enter the Rails console, and noticed that suddenly four other ruby processes showed up in my process list as above. Why would this happen? I think that running the console should create one other process and not four.

After quitting the console, I am left with three Ruby processes including the Rake task that is running.

I am using Rails 4.2.

It's not that I find this to be problematic, but I am curious why there would need to be more than one process for a REPL and then two leftover processes after the REPL is closed.

Comment: Try checking the console without the cron; you might be identifying the cron related process as console process.

Comment: @Prakash Murthy The cron finished and those two Ruby processes were left over.  I killed them, then tried Rails console.  In total, that created 4 Ruby processes.  After quitting the console, I'm back to 2 processes that just sit there indefinitely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of [spring](http://rubygems.org/gems/spring) which has shipped with rails by default for a little while now.

You might notice that the second time you run `rails c` is a lot faster than the first time. This is because the first time you run a springified script your app is loaded as normal and then forks to run what you requested. The second time around this loader script can just fork a second time, so you get a much faster startup. This possible because of these extra processes you have noticed.

You can see them by running

```
spring status
```

And you can kill them by running

```
spring stop
```